# AngularJS models, working with angular.extend(object.prototype, ...) vs angular.extend(object, ...)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on a service as a model in AngulaJS. I use a factory nad I want to use the `angular.extend()` thing to add attributes/properties to the `$resource` object.

The problem is that I can't access attributes added with this :

```
var myObject = $resource(...);

angular.extend(myObject.prototype, {
    hi : "hi",
    findFriend : function(){ console.log("You are all alone...") }
}
```

I'm not able to access "hi" or "findFriend" in my controller nor in the factory with a console.log().

But if I do this :

```
var myObject = $resource(...);

angular.extend(myObject, {
    hi : "hi",
    findFriend : function(){console.log("It works"}
}
```

Then I'm able to access those attributes. If the good practice is the second one, then what is the difference with :

```
var myObject = $resource(...);
myObject.hi = "hi";
myObject.findFriend("It works");
```

?

I read the documentation and followed [this article to build my model](https://gist.github.com/alanctkc/aefb176d5be9b132dd7c#link-to-new-post).

Can someone explain why one work and not the other ? Why it seems to be different from the article ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your `var myObject` is not an instance of a class so extending the prototype will add method for instance not for class. $resource return a "class" object so you need to instanciate an instance of myObject by using new myObject().

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What should I do so, is it bad to stay with the myObject = $resource() then modify with angular.Extend(myObject, ...) ?

Comment: No it is not bad, but you are not doing OOP, and it suggest that you instantiate your class.